# Shrink wallpaper bitmap drawable to reduce RAM usage

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-wallpaper

I am currently using device wallpaper as my layout background. The bitmap drawable size is very large on on some devices about 7 MB in Samsung S3. Is there any way to reduce this without consuming more RAM. I am worried about OOM on low memory devices.

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(mContext);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
bitmapDrawable.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
} else {
                layout.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BitmapFactory.Options` but should convert `BitmapDrawable` to `byte[]`

```
 //convert BitmapDrawable to byte[]
//winsize is height screen user device 
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
        if (options.outHeight >= (CampainManager.winSize )) {
            int x = (options.outHeight / (winSize ));
            options.inSampleSize = x;
        }
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
```

Comment: this reduces the height of image, i want to fill height. And this doesn't help me. it causes usage of extra ram 7MB(old)+2MB(compressed) .

Comment: @FazilKunhamed, did you solved it?